# Get unique values from Parent List in Dropdown List SPServices

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, spservices

I have a dropdown list created using the SPServices ($().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns). It works as it should, I just need to add a requirement. I need to be able to filter the Parent Lookup list to show only unique values.

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
relationshipList: "ROInsComp",
relationshipListParentColumn: "AIP-RY",
relationshipListChildColumn: "NameAndCode",
parentColumn: "AIP-RY",
childColumn: "NameAndCode",
debug: true
```

});

The issue is that in AIP-RY I have stored Years and each year could be repeted several times:
[image]

Is this even possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to try another way. SPCascadeDropdowns can use a CAML Query, but a CAML Query can not return the unique items the way you want.

There are a number of options discussed on the SPServices Discussion Forums for [getting unique items from a list](https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/274126).

I like Frederik's option of returning the HTML for a dropdown from the filter.aspx

```
$.ajax({
url: weburl+'/_layouts/filter.aspx?ListId='+escape(listId)+'&FieldInternalName='+internalName+'&ViewId='+escape(viewId)+'&FilterOnly=1&Filter=1',
success: function(data) {
    //Do Something
}
```

});

Comment: Tom, thanks for the answer, but I don't get this to work. This is what I've done so far: `$.ajax({
url: weburl+'https://my-site/_layouts/filter.aspx?ListId='+escape('{544C8B6A-C9B3-4BAD-B9CF-B032E5FD07DB}')+'&FieldInternalName='+"AP_x0020_Year" + '&ViewId='+escape('{4B433420-156F-4F4F-9E3C-551DC43B593C}')+'&FilterOnly=1&Filter=1',
success: function(data) {
    alert('It worked!');}
});` I wonder what am i doing wrong. thanks again!

Comment: I think it's a formatting issue. I notice in Frederik's code he uses a javascript function called escape around the GUIDs. It may be this will help http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointcomic/archive/2008/12/09/url-decoder-encoder-guid-converter.aspx

Comment: Thanks again! I actually used a similar one: [http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php ] for ma code above.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked!